how to dockerize a mongodb replica set with both encryption at rest and in transit (SSL) enabled
I would like to setup a mongodb replica set with both encryption at rest and in transit, with docker.
By encryption at rest, it's meant that stored data is encrypted, and "in transit" means the connection between client and mongodb is also encrypted (tls/ssl enabled).
Most of the articles I find don't show a proper setup, are not complete or buggy.
Any link, git repository, or tip would be appreaciated. Thanks.

Which articles did you use? Start with Deploy a Self-Managed Replica Set, then check Configure mongod and mongos for TLS/SSL and Encryption at Rest

What did you try so far?

I have read all those articles, but my goal is to create the mongo replica instance with encryption at rest and transit with Docker. The closest article I found is this https://dev.to/prestonvasquez/dockerizing-a-mongodb-replica-set-with-tlsssl-20e2
I fixed it to make it work, but still can't use and doesn't include stored data encryption

In deed, file provided mongodb.conf is crap. For encryption at rest have a look at official MongoDB documentation. You will find much less samples for it, because it is available only in MongoDB Enterprise Edition (which is not for free)

Thanks Wernfried, you are right. Do you know any resource (book, article) that shows a good example using the enterprise edition? Something more verbose then the example-free mongo documentation? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/core/security-data-encryption/

Well, in principle you only have to set parameter security.encryptionCipherMode and security.encryptionKeyFile and then restart the cluster. Not that difficult.
